# FAN6754 flyback converter-overcurrent problem

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, flyback

I have a flyback converter design with a 193 V output voltage and 700 mA current, but when the current is drawn from the output, the auxilary winding voltage falls down, and the IC shuts down the PWM gate signal (as you can see in the attachment), and the output voltage goes to zero.

And I don't understand why the auxilary voltage is like a sawtooth wave; I think the IC tries to open PWM but can not start.

Can any body help me with this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Decreasing R9 and increasing C9 would tend to provide VCCP for a longer time. This may help "ride through" until the next pulse comes.

Comment: Actually I tried 18R and 0R for R9 but result is same as you can see in ossiloscope screen.

Comment: Which channel is which signal?

Comment: @ivanmateo are we done with this question and answer now? If not then please leave a comment for further clarification else formally accept my answer. If you are unaware how to do this [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).

Comment: @ivanmateo are we done with this question and answer now? See also the comment immediately above and take note that if you wish to receive the full attention and help of folk on this site, you should remember that upvoting useful answers and accepting the best answer is good practice and a sign of respect to those giving their free time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The FAN6754 will shut down when the supply drops below 9 volts and not restart until that voltage rises above 16.5 volts. Given that it can work at a peak supply voltage that is closer to 30 volts, it seems that more turns on your auxiliary winding might be the route to go.

Comment: Actually as you can in waveform it comes nearly 16.5V, but it can not start, the voltage is drop again. It can be related to R8,R9 or V1, because if the current is enough to turn to zener, voltage will be 22V but also voltage is dropping.

Comment: The o scope shots don’t give me enough detail to recognise that. What switching frequency are you using?

Comment: 65Khz. The scope show c9 and c10 voltage.

Comment: Unloaded, what do those voltages look like and please remember I don’t know where your 0 volt references on the scope are nor, which colour is which signal. Try and show max and min rather than max and mean.

Comment: Yellow is C9 voltage and Green is C10. But it must settle in 22V due to zener, but it fall down.

Comment: Use a 27 volt zener diode and see what happens. You still need more turns on your six winding though I reckon.

Comment: I will try it. I have 7 turns in aux.

Comment: @ivanmateo did you resolve this? Was this answer useful? If so then please formally accept this answer else, raise another comment and ask a related question. I think also you need to know a little more about the etiquette on this site so [please take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why people (like me) give help for free.

Comment: @ivanmateo please read and act on this --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and, if you need any help finding the answer accept button look at this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png <-- after all, you don't want folk thinking your are mean-spirited in case the help they give you dwindles off.